# Why is my footer not showing on the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css

One of my pages from my website is not showing the footer in the bottom of the page. I've already done some pages and it is working well with the same code, but I don't know why in this page is not working well. This is the HTML code for the footer (which I want to display the social media icons from Font Awesome):

```
<footer>
<div class="fa">
    <a class="media" href="https://www.instagram.com/massaviu/" target="_blank">
        <i class="fab fa-instagram grow" style="color: #E1306C"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="media" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCh1_-QpgzIdG-3QfCMfZi6w" target="_blank">
        <i class="fab fa-youtube grow" style="color: #FF0000"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="media" href="https://open.spotify.com/artist/0du3FPmKtQ8vfsmGYVzdFY" target="_blank">
        <i class="fab fa-spotify grow" style="color: #1DB954"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="media" href="https://music.apple.com/us/artist/massaviu/1378812000" target="_blank">
        <i class="fab fa-apple grow" style="color:  #A3AAAE"></i>
    </a>
</div> </footer>
```

This is the css I've already used in different pages that actually works, but not in this one:

```
footer {  text-align: center;  bottom: 0;}

.media {    display: inline-block;  width: 60px; height: 90px;  margin: 10px;}

.media i {  color: white;   font-size: 50px;}

.media:hover i {    opacity: 0.7;}

.grow { transition: all .2s ease-in-out; }
.grow:hover { transform: scale(1.3); }
```

Comment: looking at this code, it should work. is there any other code that might interact with the footer? or even jump onto of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This flex css3 Example It may help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
            min-height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        section {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }

        footer {
            background: #000;
            text-align: center;
            color: #fff;
            display: flex;
            align-self: flex-end;
            width: 100%;
            justify-content: center;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>


    <section>this is body section</section>
    <footer>this is footer</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see you had used the `bottom:0` without position absolute or fix. Please make sure that `bottom` property work with respect to position.

Answer (score 0):

`bottom: 0` only works in conjunction with `position: absolute`, `position: relative`, `position: fixed` or `position: sticky`.

You want `position: absolute`. This one will take the whole page/document as basis and let you specify where your element should be positioned in relation to it.

So try this:

```css
footer { text-align: center;  bottom: 0; position: absolute; }
```

More on this topic:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 0):

Change the footer CSS into following

```css
footer {  text-align: center;  bottom: 0; position:fixed}

.media {    display: inline-block;  width: 60px; height: 90px;  margin: 10px;}

.media i {  color: white;   font-size: 50px;}

.media:hover i {    opacity: 0.7;}

.grow { transition: all .2s ease-in-out; }
.grow:hover { transform: scale(1.3); }
```

You can try with position as absolute too.